# Create DFA for the regular expression of a real number?

Tags: regex, dfa

I'm trying to construct the Definite Finite Automata(DFA) of a real number, that is defined as:

- A string leading with an optional '+' or '-'.
- Followed by a single zero or non-empty sequence of digits that doesn't start with a zero.
- Followed by a decimal point.
- Followed by a non-empty sequence of digits

And its finish depends on digits if its real or not.

I constructed the regular expression: `/[+ | -]?(O | ([1-9][0-9]*)).[0-9]+/`

Comment: What is the issue ? How does your code differ from your expected output ?

Comment: I always find [online regex testers](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+regex+tester&oq=online+regex+tester&aqs=chrome..69i57.3994j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) helpful when constructing/testing/debugging regex expressions.  For example: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Is there a special test case that your expression fails ? Could you provide a couple test strings that you would like to see pass ?

Comment: From this regular exception i want to draw DFA. how can i do that ?

Comment: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IE4LcyIfGOk/maxresdefault.jpg something like that i have to do  think.

Comment: Having the regular expression, first create a Thompson-NFA from it, eliminate epsilon transitions and determinize it. Should be quite easy because the Thomson-NFA is already almost deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/SyTBqw/1)

```
^[+-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?$
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[+-]?` Optionally match either `+` or `-`
- `(?:0|[1-9]\d*)` Match either `0` or a number beginning with a digit in the range of `1-9`, followed by any number of any digit
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Optionally match a decimal point number (a dot `.`, followed by one or more digits)
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

[image: DFA]

Here, start state is `q0`.

Final state is `q5`.

DFA enters state `q1` if sign is provided.

State `q2` is reached if the first digit is 0.

State `q3` if the first digit is not 0 and remains in that state for further numbers till a decimal point is seen.

State `q4` reached on decimal point from where there is transition to state `q5` if a digit is seen.

Dead state is not shown.